# Windows' recommendation for monitor's resolution: what's the basis?

Tags: windows, display, resolution

In Windows, a resolution is recommended for each monitor. What's the basis of this recommendation, .i.e how does Windows decide what the recommended resolution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window's recommendation is the monitor's [native](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_resolution) resolution. This is "usually the highest resolution your monitor can support."

Source: the [how to](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/getting-best-display-monitor#getting-best-display-monitor=windows-7) portion of the Windows site.

Comment: Obviously it would have been too easy to write "native resolution" instead of "recommended resolution"…